# How to save a listWidget's properties?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget

I have a listWidget that gets populated from a csv file. If a user clicks an item in the listWidget it highlights green if it is white, and highlights white if green. With several items in the list, after some interaction from the user some of the items may be green while others remain white. Is there a way to save the status of the listWidget so that it can be read back in the next time the application is run, showing what the user previous selected as green highlighted items?

```
def getFileName(self):
    global taps
    global percent        
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    List = open(fileName).readlines()
    self.listWidget.clear()
    self.listWidget.addItems(List)
    for lines in List:
        taps +=1
        self.label_4.setText(str(taps))            
    percent = 100.0/taps

    self._white = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
    self._green = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green)

    for i in range(0, taps):
         self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(i)
         currentItem = self.listWidget.currentItem()
         currentItem.setBackground(self._white)
    self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
    self.label_2.setText('0')
    self.label_6.setText('0')

def listChoice(self):
    #global value
    global consumed
    global remaining
    global percent
    global taps
    global newpercent

    currentItem = self.listWidget.currentItem() 
    color = currentItem.background()

    if color == self._white:
        currentItem.setBackground(self._green)
        consumed +=1
        taps = taps - 1
        newpercent += percent

    elif color == self._green:
        currentItem.setBackground(self._white)
        consumed -=1
        taps = taps + 1
        newpercent = newpercent - percent        

    currentItem.setSelected(False)
```

I didn't find what I was looking for probably because it doesn't exist, but I did find a work around.

```
def saveFile(self, showDialog):
    savePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Tap Room", 
        "Testing.csv", "CSV files (*.csv)")
    with open(savePath, 'w') as theFile:
        for i in xrange(self.listWidget.count()):                
            self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(i)
            currentItem = self.listWidget.currentItem() 
            color = currentItem.background()                                                

            if color == self._green:                    
                theFile.write(str(self.listWidget.item(i).text()))
                theFile.write('Visited: ' + 
                    (str(self.listWidget.item(i).text())))
            else:                    
                theFile.write(str(self.listWidget.item(i).text()))
```

Comment: You can use `getSelected` for each item and save that.

Comment: If I iterate through the list and use getSelcted.item(i) for each item, how would I put that all together in a file for use later?

Comment: I've since learned how add checkBoxes and to get the checkedState of each checkbox. I just don't know how to repackage the results which would be the ltem and the checkedState.

Comment: @JeffreyShama I would like to try to solve your problem but before that I need you to clarify the following questions: 1) Let's say you load the a.csv file and make the selection you point out (change the color of the highlight) and somehow keep it, then what happens if instead of loading the a.csv file loads another file? Should you keep those highlights from the a.csv file? 2) Based on the above, you can upload n files. What happens in those cases?

Comment: I check for "Visited is in" when reading the file back in, and make the listwidget litem unselectable/uneditable so the user can't resellect the place and erroneously change the other variables I was keeping track of.  It now works as desired.  I am still very interested in my original question if a widgets properties can be 'saveable' somehow. I had a much more detailed answer but ran over the max characters.